# Create a Button with right triangle/pointer

Tags: css, css-shapes

Looking to create this: [image: button with right arrow/pointer]

What would be the best way to achieve it?

**IT MUST:** 
I'd definitely like to keep the text as text (so not using an image). Also, I'd like this to be re-usable so that I can put different text in it.
Ideally, the arrow part should be as high as the text.

**NICE TO HAVE:** 
I'd like to be able to drop this on any background (so it isn't always on white)
Would be great if it was ie8+

Thanks!!

Comment: I'd tried a few ways such as pseudo elements, border and semi transparent background images but non of them were great for various reasons. Didn't seem worth sticking up a load of semi failed experiments that wouldn't have made much sense.

Comment: You can put up one experiment to show us you're actively trying and not just asking "give me teh codez!" :) We like to see effort here, hehe.

Comment: Fair comment hadn't realised people thought in that way. Don't want to offend anyone. Also thanks to those who helped my out anyway.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have you tried something using html/css??

```css
#vert_menu{   overflow: hidden;  width: 100%; }
#vert_menu li{  float: left; }
#vert_menu a{
  padding: 8px 20px 8px 40px;
  float: left; text-align:center;
  text-decoration: none; font: normal 16px Myriad Pro, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;  text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #000;
  color: #e6e2cf;
  position: relative; text-shadow:1px 0 0 #000;
  background: #525252;  min-width:181px; width:auto
}

#vert_menu a::after,
#vert_menu a::before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -19px;   
  border-top: 19px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 19px solid transparent;
  border-left: 1em solid;
  right: -1em;
}
#vert_menu a::after{   z-index: 2;  border-left-color: #525252;   }
```

```html
<ul id="vert_menu">
<li><a href="#" class="current">test</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I'd been trying but couldn't quite pull off. In the code that I've used I took off the float on the href and just made it display:inline-block. This was so it could be used with centrally aligned text. I also changed the "::" to ":" which added support for ie8 (although is now using slightly older syntax as I understand it) MANY THANKS!!!!!

Comment: WC :) That was the sample code which I have used in my project. It just give u an idea to get the effect, you can modify according to your requirement

Comment: Of course - thanks. Just added the bits that I changed to the comment in case someone else found it useful. Didn't mean to imply that your code was wrong in anyway! Again thanks so much for this!

Answer (score 4):

You may this in your HTML;

```
<div>
    <a href="#"><button>Button</button></a>
</div>
```

And this in your CSS

```
a {
    background: #950006;
    border: none;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 28px;
    line-height: 28px;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100px
}

a:before{
    background: #950006;
    border: none;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    left: 90px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    width: 21px;
}
a button {
    color: #fff;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    width: 120px;
    height: 28px;
}
```

and will output a button like this:- [image]

***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/SMJYy/)*** is a working Live Demo. The complete button is CLICKABLE. You may test the button by changing the background of the parent div.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for this, it very nearly worked but IE9 had trouble with the rotate so looked a bit broken...

Comment: Best option out there.

Answer (score 0):

Alfred's solution did the trick to get a right arrow button. I wanted this to be dynamic so I could reuse it across multiple projects and easily adjust the width and height of the button. I was able to use CSS variables to do the calculations to modify the button according to the base width and height. This can be tweaked even further by moving the text of the button to be centered taking into place the addition of the triangle on the right.

See live demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/azarue/7bdhm825/

```css
.arrow-button-container {
    --arrow-button-width: 160;
    --arrow-button-height: 58;
    --arrow-button-bg-color: #b8282e;
    background: var(--arrow-button-bg-color);
    border: none;
    display: inline-block;
    height: calc(1px * var(--arrow-button-height));
    line-height: calc(1px * var(--arrow-button-height));
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: calc(1px * var(--arrow-button-width));
    cursor: pointer;
}

.arrow-button-container:before{
    --rotate-square-side: calc(1px * var(--arrow-button-height) / sqrt(2));
    background: var(--arrow-button-bg-color);
    border: none;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    left: calc(1px * var(--arrow-button-width) - 1px * var(--arrow-button-height) / sqrt(2) / 2);
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(var(--rotate-square-side)/sqrt(2) - var(--rotate-square-side)/2);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg); 
    transform: rotate(45deg); 
    width: var(--rotate-square-side);
    height: var(--rotate-square-side);
}

.arrow-button-container button {
    color: #fff;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    width: calc(1px * var(--arrow-button-width));
    height: calc(1px * var(--arrow-button-height));
}
```

```html
<a class="arrow-button-container" href="#">
  <button>Button</button>
</a>
```