# How to make a triangular onfocus?

Tags: css, css-shapes

I need to do a triangular onfocus on button, like on this image

[image: triangular onfocus button]

I looked at different examples like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12071972/create-a-button-with-right-triangle-pointer), but the focus zone is rectangular.

Is it possible make triangular onfocus?

Comment: Are you open to using images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `clip-path` to give a triangular shape to the `button` and  apply the same shape to `button::before` pseudoelement slightly enlarged to mimic an outline, e.g.

> [Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pyLXOp)

*Note: working only on browser supporting* `clip-path`

**Markup**

```
<button><span>button</span></button>
```

**CSS**

```
button {
  position: relative;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 50% 100% 0);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 50% 100% 0);
}

button span {  
  position: relative; 
  z-index: 1; 
  display: block;
  background: linear-gradient(#f4f4f4, #d4d4d4);
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

button:focus {
  outline: none;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 90% 100%, 100% 50%, 90% 0);  
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 90% 100%, 100% 50%, 90% 0);  
}

button::before,
button span {
   -webkit-clip-path: inherit;
   clip-path: inherit; 
} 

button:focus::before {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   height: calc(100% + 4px);
   width: calc(100% + 4px);
   left: -2px;
   top: -2px;
   background: rgba(81,153,219, .7);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `map` tag : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

But in that case your button must be a picture.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this?
Adding an element after the button to provide the triangular shape...

Now it is 45° rotation, you could play by skewing to get another angle.

[CodePen Sample](https://codepen.io/yoeri/pen/JXLQBz)

```
button:hover { border-color: blue; }
button:hover:after { border-color: blue;}

button {
  font-size: 14px;
  background: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-right: 0;
  position: relative;
  height: 44px;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
button::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px; height: 30px;
  background: #FFF;
  right: -15px;
  top: 5px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  z-index:-1;
  border-right: 1px solid Red;
  border-bottom: 1px solid Red;
}
```

Comment: Add radius in button::after to get a rounded angle: border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;

Answer (score 0):

little late,

but **you can do for almost every browser with `transform` and a pseudo**.

Eventually add background gradient and shadow : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/yOjOby

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
a {

  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  margin: 0 1.5em 0 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #177EE5;
  border: solid 3px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-right: none;
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, lightgray, white, lightgray);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
}
a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  bottom: 3px;
  right: -.8em;
  width: 1.75em;
  border-radius: inherit;
  border-top: solid;
  border-right: solid;
  border-color: inherit;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 45%, lightgray 60%);
  box-shadow: 0px -5px  5px -5px black, 5px 0px  5px -5px black
}
```

```html
<a href="#">arrow</a>
<a href="#">longer arrow</a>
<a href="#">@</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use this site and make triangular, polygon: The Shapes of CSS - CSS-Tricks

https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS

make a css class. add that class on focus.

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_addclass.asp